# Javascript regex starts with a square bracket and a letter and ends with a square bracket

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find index of some string that starts with `[S` and ends with `]`, basicly it could look like `[S12]`.The whole idea will be to get this "12" value , get start index, and its ending tag start index, and will replace it with some values depending on what value it had.

I dont have any experience with regex. I started something like this

```
var pattern = /(^[S&,])/;
var string = 'Text that [S0]has new[/S0] tag '
var result = pattern.test(string);
```

But cant really get it to work. If I am not to mistaken , this pattern means it starts with `[S` and ends with `]`.

My desired result would be `Text that <span class="class12">has new</span> tag`

Here is jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/970ygfkh/

Any documentation/post/help is good :)

Comment: Where's the semicolon ?

Comment: `[S&,]` is a character class allowing one of those characters (`S`, `&`, or `,`). The `^` is the start of the string. Your string doesn't start with any of those characters so it doesn't  match.. Also note `;` is a semi-colon. `[` is a bracket.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake in header.
@chris85 Hmm so what is the proper way to approach my problem

Comment: Do you want to convert [S0]has new[/S0] to [S0] ?? Not sure what you are asking.. Please post the desired result.

Comment: `/\[S(.*?)\]/g` <- more like that

Comment: @chris85 Yep , nailed it, i can work with this. Post it as answer :)
adeneo Also works

Comment: Okay, I've moved that as an awnser.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use:

```
\[(S\d+)\]+(.*?)\[\/\1\]
```

to capture the text between `[s`, any number, and a closing `]` and the matching closing block. Using this regex the containing text will be in the second capture group.

In your first regex `(^[S&,])` that `[S&,]` is allowing a `S`, `&`, or `,`. The `^` is the start of the string and the `()` captured the value. So only a string starting with `S`, `&` or `,` would have matched/been captured.

You can see an explanation of my regex on regex101, https://regex101.com/r/nmWbEG/1.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
\[(\w\d+)\](.*)\[\/\1]
```

Should capture any letter (if you only want S then replace \w with S) followed by any amount of digits (so you have the tag) and the content of it as long as there is a closing tag for it ie:

```
[W20]this is a test[/W20]
```

Would capture

```
W20
```

and

```
this is a test
```

https://regex101.com/r/uiLlM0/1 for examples